# How to install RHEL 7 through pendrive?

Tags: linux, rhel

I have 7gb RHEL 7 image file. I used UniBoot to make pendrive bootable. But when i try to install during startup of pc, grub cmd screen comes every time. What to do??

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have got the solution. I follow these steps

1. yum install syslinux
2. isohybrid /path/to/isofile
3. dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdx

It works. 
Syslinux is actually a bootloader compatible with most of the distro.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there's already a Linux distro installed on your machine, and your machine is booting from the hard drive.

You need either to:

1. setup your BIOS and change the order of the boot devices to put USB as first, or
2. at boot, press the appropriate key (depends on your machine, I can't be more specific on this point) that pops up a menu allowing you to choose the device to boot from.

Comment: Yes I chose the same pendrive. But after that grub> command prompt came instead of GUI of installation.

Comment: Do you have another machine on which you can test the pendrive? If yes, please try it and post the results.

Comment: I have virtual machine on the same system and it works fine. Is there any alternative to do bootable pendrive??  I used dd command also but the result was same

Comment: If it's a rhel7 installation ISO it might come up with a GRUB prompt if it's booting uEFI.